# Amulet of mighty fists, spell storing item and temporary natural weapons

Tags: pathfinder-1e

If I use an [Amulet of Mighty Fists](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-mighty-fists) to give [Spell Storing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/spell-storing) to the natural weapons granted by the [Dragon Shaman](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/dragon-shaman)'s Totem Transformation ability, when the natural weapons go away, do they retain the spells I cast on them or do the spells disappear when the natural weapons do?

I can see it going both ways, since you still have your teeth and nails.

**(Please assume that the amulet "gives" the enchantment to your natural weapons, rather than having an enchantment that applies to the natural weapons, meaning that spell storing would be instanced by each natural weapon)**

Answer (score 9):

The *Spell Storing* is not linked to a specific natural weapon.

From the [Amulet of Mighty Fists](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-mighty-fists):

> This amulet grants an enhancement bonus of +1 to +5 on attack and damage rolls with unarmed attacks and natural weapons. Alternatively, this amulet can grant melee weapon special abilities, so long as they can be applied to unarmed attacks.

The above text implies that the bonuses and special abilities apply to any and all unarmed attacks and natural weapons you possess.  Because it applies to all natural attacks, when you store a spell in an amulet with the *Spell Storing* ability, it isn't linked to a specific natural weapon; the spell can be discharged with any attack the *Amulet* enhances.

So if you store a spell, you can discharge the spell with an unarmed strike or from any other natural weapon you possess.  If you lose a natural weapon, the spell is still stored in the *Amulet*, and will remain there until you choose to discharge it (with a different natural weapon, or the same one after you reacquire it). The important part is that the spell is stored in the *Amulet* itself.

Comment: That would be a reasonable house-rule, but I don't see how it at all follows from the text you quote.

Comment: @topquark If you put Flaming on the amulet instead of Spell Storing, it applies to every natural weapon you possess. Why should Spell Storing function any differently?

Comment: The question is about a distinction that's irrelevant for Flaming and most other weapon abilities, so that analogy doesn't help answer it. (And it's likewise understandable that the author of the amulet might not have thought of this edge case.) The distinction is: Either each natural weapon gets an independent instance of Spell Storing (and can each store a separate spell), or you have only one instance of Spell Storing that simultaneously applies to all of your natural weapons (and can only store one spell total).

Comment: There's no precedent for an item ability to be duplicated over multiple weapon faces. An imperfect comparison (hence I didn't mention it in the answer) is a double weapon. You can attack with both sides of the weapon, but it's treated as one magic item with one set of item abilities shared by both sides (this was changed from D&D 3.5, when each side of the weapon was made magical separately). There's no reason the amulet would work any differently. It's one item, and the ability is shared over multiple attacks of the same creature.  But it's an imperfect comparison, so it isn't in the answer.

Comment: @topquark Considering it doesn't mention the ability to provide different special abilities to different natural weapons and that all natural weapons benefit from the special abilities I'm inclined to believe that it's a passive enchant to all natural weapons you possess. 

As such we either have to accept that, if you have more than one natural weapon, then you can store more than one spell. Though there is no real rule-based precedent for it with this in mind I'm inclined to agree with WeirdFrog that all natural weapons should be considered one natural weapon for effects from the amulet

Comment: I think you need to answer the question.  When the natural weapons of the Dragon Shaman's Totem Transformation "go away. . ."   the effect of the spell should also be discharged as they are no longer there.  Once you reactivate this Dragon Shaman Totem Transformation, the Amulet and its Melee Weapon Special Ability of Spell Storing can then apply again.  Without knowing the spell stored it is harder to answer your ??  I agree with WierdFrog the Amulet's effect applies to "unarmed attacks and natural weapons."

Comment: I hadn't considered that other interpretation. To me it granted the enchantment to each of your natural weapons. I guess the problem is more complicated than I imagined. I will change the question to include my assumption, because the assumption that it has an enchantment that applies to your natural weapons rather than giving them the enchantments kind of makes my question irrelevant.